# checking if values in a pandas df are inside lists in columns of a second df

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

I have 2 dataframes
df1: has 4 columns each  has column has a list inside with values
df2: has one column (col) the column has 1 value

I want to check if any of the values in df2(col) are inside any of the lists in the rows of df1(col1) or df1(col2), then save that row (df1 with the 4 columns)

Here is some random data to make an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[32, 24, 5, 6], [4, 8, 14], 
                            [12, 32, 234, 15, 6], [45]], 
                    'col2': [[13, 333 ,5], [32, 28, 5, 9], 
                            [4], [12, 45, 21]],
                    'col3': [['AS', 'EWE', 'SADF', 'EW'], 
                            ['EW', 'HHT', 'IYT'], ['C', 'KJG', 'TF', 'VC', 'D'], ['BX']], 
                    'col4': [['HG', 'FDGD' ,'F'], ['FDG', 'Y', 'FS', 'RT'], 
                            ['T'], ['XC', 'WE', 'TR']]
                    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 333, 8, 11, 45]})
```

df1:

```
                   col1            col2                 col3              col4
0        [32, 24, 5, 6]    [13, 333, 5]  [AS, EWE, SADF, EW]     [HG, FDGD, F]
1            [4, 8, 14]  [32, 28, 5, 9]       [EW, HHT, IYT]  [FDG, Y, FS, RT]
2  [12, 32, 234, 15, 6]             [4]  [C, KJG, TF, VC, D]               [T]
3                  [45]    [12, 45, 21]                 [BX]      [XC, WE, TR]
```

df2:

```
   col
0    1
1  333
2    8
3   11
4   45
```

This code works fine, but I am using big data, so it takes a lot to finish.
So I am wondering if there is any way to optimize it.

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if (any(itm in row['col1'] for itm in df2['col'])):
        df3 = df3.append(row)
    elif (any(itm in row['col2'] for itm in df2['col'])):
        df3 = df3.append(row)
```

And this is what the output would look like:

```
             col1            col2                 col3              col4
0  [32, 24, 5, 6]    [13, 333, 5]  [AS, EWE, SADF, EW]     [HG, FDGD, F]
1      [4, 8, 14]  [32, 28, 5, 9]       [EW, HHT, IYT]  [FDG, Y, FS, RT]
3            [45]    [12, 45, 21]                 [BX]      [XC, WE, TR]
```

The output can be either a new df or a column in df1 with '1' or '0' if the value is or not in any of the two columns.

UPDATE:

Following  cs95 approach, I was able to improve the performance of the code.

My previous code would take 55s, with his approach it's only 8ms, so a speedup of around x690.

Comment: Hello and thanks for accepting. What is the speedup factor of the revised solution?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I will look more into writting more efficient code. The speedup factor was around x690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, we can use setlookups to speed this up:

```
lookup = {*df2['col']}
df1[~df1[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lookup.isdisjoint).all(axis=1)]

             col1            col2                 col3              col4
0  [32, 24, 5, 6]    [13, 333, 5]  [AS, EWE, SADF, EW]     [HG, FDGD, F]
1      [4, 8, 14]  [32, 28, 5, 9]       [EW, HHT, IYT]  [FDG, Y, FS, RT]
3            [45]    [12, 45, 21]                 [BX]      [XC, WE, TR]
```

Dealing with column of lists is hard. We can make things easier by recognizing we can use `applymap` since every cell in `df1['col1']` and `df1['col2']` have to undergo the same check (a lookup on `df2['col']`). Then use a little boolean logic to determine what rows to drop and you have the final result.

Your code contains a double whammy with the use of `iterrows` and `append`. Never iterate over a DataFrame because it is slow and wastes memory, and never grow a DataFrame for the same reasons.

---

```
lookup
# {1, 8, 11, 45, 333}

# get cells that have no elements in common
df1[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lookup.isdisjoint)

    col1   col2
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True   True
3  False  False

# get rows who have no columns in common
df1[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lookup.isdisjoint).all(axis=1)
 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

# invert the condition to get rows to keep
~df1[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(lookup.isdisjoint).all(axis=1)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```